# font-awesome-pro-sass gem's fa-regular-400 and fa-solid-900 files are larger in size ( ~400kb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, asset-pipeline, font-awesome-6

I am using `font-awesome-pro-sass` gem ( v6.5.1 ) with my rails application following the [docs](https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/use-with/ruby-on-rails). Noticed that the font files that are being fetched by the browser are large, and are taking considerable amount of time for content fetching.

These files in font awesome pro kits are relatively smaller.

Is there a way to reduce the size of these files being used or other ways of using this, or other way to compress these files alone, without affecting other assets.

Comment: Pro kits support auto-subsetting (stripping your font to used icons) See ["css-tricks: Subsetting Font Awesome to Improve Performance"](https://css-tricks.com/subsetting-font-awesome-to-improve-performance/) If you're using the free version you may create  a custom subset using a tool like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/)